# BISON AST production prints scrambled values

Tags: c, compiler-construction, bison, abstract-syntax-tree, yacc

I'm trying to make a simple parser. It's for a homework assignment but also for own experimentation. I have completed the lexer and the parser and I'm trying now to output an AST. The problem is that when I'm adding, for example, two integers, the result tree is printed with unrecognizable symbols. A valid input should be `+(1,1)` and a valid output should be `(+ 1 1)`. Instead of this, I'm getting `( +  �|k  �|k )`. I've tried many things, without actually any significant result. The `sprintf` function returns a null terminator, so probably this is not the problem. Below is the **parser** code (.y file):

```
%{
#define YYDEBUG 1
%}

%start program

%token  NUMBER
%token  ID
%token  PLUS    MINUS   TIMES
%token  LP  RP  EQUALS  COMMA
%token  END

%token  LET IN  AND

%left   PLUS    MINUS
%left   TIMES
%left   LET IN  AND
%left   EQUALS

%%

program:{printf("Empty Input\n");}  /* empty */
        | program line /* do nothing */

line:   expr END        { printtree($1); printf("\n");}
    ;

expr    : /*Empty*/
    | LET deflist IN expr {}
    | ID        { printf("Found ID\n"); $$ = make_id_leaf($1);}
    | NUMBER    { printf("Found NUMBER\n"); $$ = make_number_leaf($1);}
        | PLUS LP expr COMMA expr RP  {$$ = make_plus_tree($3,$5); printf("Found expr PLUS expr.\n"); }
        | TIMES LP expr COMMA expr RP {$$ = make_times_tree($3,$5); printf("Found expr TIMES expr. Result:%d\n", $$);}
    | MINUS ID
    | MINUS NUMBER     { printf("found MINUS NUMBER\n"); }
        ;

deflist : definition
    | definition AND deflist
    ;

definition : /*Empty*/
       | ID EQUALS expr {printf("Found EQ\n");}
       ;
%%

/*int main (void) {return yyparse ( );}*/

int yyerror (char *s) {fprintf (stderr, "%s\n", s);}
```

The **lexer** file:

```
%{
#include "parser.h"
%}
DIGIT [0-9]
LETTER [a-zA-Z]
%%

LET {printf("Encountered LET\n"); return(LET);}
IN  {printf("Encountered IN\n"); return(IN);}
AND {printf("Encountered AND\n"); return(AND);}
{DIGIT}+    {yylval = atoi(yytext); return NUMBER;}
{LETTER}*       { if (strlen(yytext) <= 8){
                    yylval = strlen(yytext);
            printf( "<ID, %s> ", yytext );
            return(ID);
                  } else {
                        yytext[8] = '\0';
                        printf("WARNING! Long identifier. Truncating to 8 chars\n");
                        printf( "<ID, %s> ", yytext );
            return(ID);
                  }
                }
[ \t] ;
[\n]     return(END); 
"+"      return(PLUS);
"-"      return(MINUS);
"*"      return(TIMES);
"="  return(EQUALS);
"("      return(LP);
")"      return(RP);
","  return(COMMA);
<<EOF>>  return(0);
%%

int yywrap (void) {return 1;}
```

The **main.c** which includes the **yyparse()** function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "tree.h"
#include "treedefs.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    yyparse();

    return 0;
}
```

And the **treedefs.h** file which includes the function definitions (I've included only the struct definition, the number leaf and the plus tree):

```
typedef struct tree{
    char *token;
    TREE *l;
    TREE *r;
    TREE *child;
}TREE;

/* Make number leaves */

TREE *make_number_leaf(int n){

    TREE *leafNum = malloc(sizeof(TREE));

    char *c, ch[8];
    sprintf(ch, "%d", n); /* Effective way to convert int to string */
    c = ch;
    leafNum->token = c;
    leafNum->l = NULL;
        leafNum->r = NULL;
        leafNum->child = NULL;

    printf("NUM Leaf is: %s\n", leafNum->token);

    return (leafNum);
}

/* Addition tree */

TREE *make_plus_tree(TREE *l, TREE *r){

    TREE *plusTree = malloc(sizeof(TREE));

    plusTree->token = "+";
    plusTree->l = l;
    plusTree->r = r;
    plusTree->child = NULL;

    return (plusTree);

}
void printtree(TREE *tree)
{
    if (tree->l || tree->r){
            printf("(");
    }

    printf(" %s ", tree->token);

    if (tree->l){
        printtree(tree->l);
    }
    if (tree->r){
        printtree(tree->r);
    }
    if (tree->l || tree->r){
        printf(")");
    }
}
```

The file **tree.h** includes only some declarations, no big deal, and definitely not related to the issue.

Why the numbers look like this? And how can I fix it? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem actually has nothing to do with bison or flex. It's in your `make_number_leaf` implementation:

```
TREE *make_number_leaf(int n){
    TREE *leafNum = malloc(sizeof(TREE));
    char *c, ch[8];
    //       ^ local variable
    sprintf(ch, "%d", n); /* Effective way to convert int to string */
    c = ch;
    leafNum->token = c;
    //               ^ dangling pointer
    // Remainder omitted
 }
```

As indicated in the comments above, `ch` is a local (stack-allocated) variable, whose lifetime ends when the function returns. Assigning its address to the variable `c` does nothing to change that. So the value of `c` which is stored into `leafNum->token` will become a dangling pointer as soon as the function returns.

So when you later attempt to print out the token, you are printing out the contents of random memory.

You need to `malloc` a character buffer, and remember to `free` it when you are `free`ing the `TREE`. (However, in the case where `leafNum->token` is a string literal, you cannot call `free`, so you need to be a bit cleverer.)